# book printing service ecommerce frontend

Tags: magento-1.8

I wish to implement a book printing service e-commerce frontend; how can I configure the catalog?

End user product price depends on:

1. number of pages per volume
2. extra attributed per page (quantity of print colors, paper type, ...)
3. number of copies requested
4. extra attributes per volume (binding, cover type, ...)

So price is something like `#pages * base page price + #pages * page_extra_options_cost + #copies * base volume price + #copies * extra attributes cost`

Comment: I'm trying with mageworx's Advanced Product Options extension (http://www.mageworx.com/advanced-product-options-magento-extension.html). it seems to make the job as required.

Answer (score 1):

Implement some JS to show the price on frontend, add a few input fields on the product view page and then implement an observer which listens on `salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore` and sets the price and saves the config based on the values passed.

And if you ask more concrete, you get a more concrete answer :-)